# Almost everywhere convergence of the Fourier series of a continuous function

Tags: fourier-analysis

I want to know if there is a *simple* proof of the almost everywhere convergence of the Fourier series of a function in $C(\mathbb{T})$. I am aware of Carleson-Hunt Theorem. I was wondering if the proof simplifies for functions in $C(\mathbb{T})$.

Thank you.

Comment: My guess is it doesn't. For example, $f\in C(T)$ gives no better decay of the Fourier coefficients than $f\in L^2(T)$.